# @fontface issues in Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, font-face

Hi I'm working on a site for a client, and I'm having a devil of a time with Firefox.

One of the @fontface fonts loads just fine (TheHandRegular) but, the second one (TheHandBold) won't seem to load. I've checked and rechecked my CSS with the W3C Validator and it check out perfectly.

This is a wordpress site hosted on media-temple and for the life of me, I can't seem to figure this one out.

http://www.healthygreenkitchen.com

Thanks so much
Sabrina

Comment: I see this in chrome: GET http://www.healthygreenkitchen.com/wp-content/themes/healthygreenkitchen/webfonts/2B06F9_0_0.woff 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.healthygreenkitchen.com/wp-content/themes/healthygreenkitchen/webfonts/2B06F9_0_0.ttf 404 (Not Found) 

Meaning your path to them is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your CSS declares each font-face twice and the second time it is looking inside a folder `webfonts` for TheHandBold but not for TheHandRegular.

```
 @font-face {
 font-family: 'TheHandRegular';
 src: url('2B06C8_0_0.eot');
 src: url('2B06C8_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('2B06C8_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
      url('2B06C8_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
 }

@font-face {
font-family: 'TheHandBold';
src: url('webfonts/2B06F9_0_0.eot');****this line****
src: url('webfonts/2B06F9_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),****this line****
url('webfonts/2B06F9_0_0.woff') format('woff'), ****this line****
url('webfonts/2B06F9_0_0.ttf') format('truetype'); ****this line****
}
```

Comment: And SOLVED!
Thank you so very much, Joseph!